# Add app to team scope after it was added to a personal scope

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

Our app needs teams scope without which it is useless. It helps people to exchange cards. However personal scope is also needed to show installation steps and then show some stats in tabs or admin data. So in app store our app provides two options: "Add" and "Add to a team".

(NB: I use Node JS Botbuilder SDK)

When added to a team, the installation flow is more or less clear: onInstallationUpdateAdd checks if conversationType === 'channel' and in that case creates all DB records and sends Welcome message to selected channel for all users to see.

However when Add button is clicked, bot is unable to post to a channel (I prompt user to select a team and then create a custom channel in that team), since it's out of the roster. In such case I proactively install app to selected team via graphClient.

Is this a preferred flow or am I overcomplicating things? I'm worried that the app is getting too complex to do a simple install.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. I'm not sure why a completely new channel is needed though?

Comment: In ideal scenario, if we add "personal" scope for your app/bot in manifest, while installing the app it will show "Add" button and on click, it will install the app/bot in personal scope.

If you want to install the app in Teams channel, we should add scope as 'team' in manifest & while installing the app, it will show you the "Add to Team" button with channel selection.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Fair enough. We thought it might be better for the product to have an isolated channel, like a collaborative workspace. But creating channel through graph makes them invisible to users which I'm struggling to figure out. So probably better just let users select existing one.